# How do I join multiple columns in one table to a column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite new to SQL, most of my other questions I have been able to answer by searching but this one seemed harder to find something similar. I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769953/joining-multiple-columns-in-one-table-to-a-single-column-in-another-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930185/sql-join-on-two-fields-in-one-table) which seemed similar, but I was not able to find an answer although I think it should be straightforward.

To simplify my database, I am trying to join two of my tables into a view.

The one table (a_main) has a mapping between a user ID (UID) and their user name (name)
The second table (log_points) has a number of columns including two users (user1 and user2). The two users are identified by user ID, but I would like to show their user names in the view.

Example

```
SELECT name, UID FROM a_main
```

returns something like

`Jeff 1234`

```
SELECT date, user1, user2 FROM log_points
```

returns

`2013-03-22 1222 1234`

I would like the view to return the users by their name instead of id.

If it was just one user, I could do a straightforward JOIN

```
SELECT date, a_main.name FROM log_points 
INNER JOIN a_main ON log_points.user1 = a_main.UID
```

but I can't figure out how to also join user2 to a_main.UID.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I am using MySQL.

EDIT found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114781/join-multiple-columns-from-one-table-to-single-column-from-another-table?rq=1).

```
SELECT t1.name AS person1, t2.name AS person2
FROM log_points t
INNER JOIN a_main t1 ON t1.UID = t.user1
INNER JOIN a_main t2 ON t2.UID = t.user1;
```

Comment: there are 2 users 1222, 1234 which act like columns in log points table...right?

Comment: I figured it out, I found a related question that solved it -

Comment: @Jeff-P then you should probably tell us what the solution were - for when someone else has somewhat the same issue as yours. ;-)

Comment: I put it at the bottom after EDIT. I wasnt sure how to add formatting to make it highlight and format as code

Comment: You can just answer your own question - it's allowed http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.name AS person1, t2.name AS person2
FROM log_points t
JOIN a_main t1 ON t1.UID = t.user1
JOIN a_main t2 ON t2.UID = t.user1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT date, (SELECT name FROM a_main where UID=user1)as user1, (SELECT name FROM a_main where UID=user2)as user2 FROM log_points.
```

Can any give insight on performance both queries.